# Java swing component location on screen off by 10 pixels on x-axis in Windows 10

Tags: java, swing, windows-10

I've got a `JFrame` that I'd like to position at the upper left corner of my display, (0,0). I set the frame location using `setLocation()` before setting it visible. This results in the correct Y position, but the X position is off by 10 pixels, i.e the frame's upper left corner is 10 pixels to the right of the edge of the screen. When I move the window closer to the left edge, `getLocationOnScreen()` starts reporting negative numbers as if the frame was off screen, which it is not. When moving the window all the way to the right side of the screen `getLocationOnScreen()` reports numbers that imply 10 pixels are off screen to the right. It's as if java/swing's view of my display is offset by 10 pixels to the right.

I've tested this under Java 8, 11, and 14 and with display scaling on and off with the same results. Under macOS, the window is placed at the correct location.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class LocationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Location Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                super.componentMoved(e);
                System.out.println(frame.getLocationOnScreen());
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("frame.getLocationOnScreen() = " + frame.getLocationOnScreen());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like specific to Windows 10. Windows seem to add a 10 pixel "shadow" around non-maximixed windows causing the window to appear 10 pixels away from the edge. You may be able to solve this bu using a custom border, or an undecorated window but both will need a decent amount of coding. Planing it at -10, -10 may actually be the easiest.

Comment: Have you tried using a different look-and-feel? You know: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("...")` In any case, the default location is the top, left corner of the screen, so maybe also try without calling `setLocation()`.

Comment: @Abra using various look and feels still results in the window being placed 10 pixels to the right of the edge of the screen. If I don't call setLocation(), the window is also in the same spot, ten pixels to the right of the edge of the screen.